# Proper procedure to take when a combative notice is added to a question

Tags: discussion, edits, flags, rollback-wars

I came upon this message added to a question's body:

[image: image calling out an SO moderator]

Given the nature of the message, I flagged the question to be reviewed by the moderation team, but didn't edit it.  I didn't edit it due to the nature of the message, because I assumed that such a message would be edit-warred to remain in the question body by the user who put it there.

Is it the right action to take, to flag the question but make no attempt to alter the content the flag is about because of the fear of creating further disruption via an edit war (even if it is only a single additional rollback by the OP after the fix edit)?

Comment: A moderator flag is probably better. That user posted a question here on meta about their deleted content and didn't want to learn (they were adamant they didn't plagirise but now seeing their mod deleted answer I can see they did). They have now plagiarised that content again and so it needs to be mod handled (the content below the screenshotted part was what they previously plagiarised).

Comment: If any user is deliberately posting rude or offensive content —as they clearly do here— trying to deal with it yourself is bound to aggravate matters. You did well leaving it to a moderator and leaving the text unaltered.

Comment: Generally, if they have a problem with moderator actions they shouldn't rant about that in answers/comments but bring it up on meta. (Or in extreme situations contact SO.) It isn't really clear if this is referring to a diamond moderator or user moderators though... because in case a diamond mod would determine that something is plagiarised, they would delete the post and from there on the OP can edit it as much as they like... Similarly if user moderators found a case for plagiarism, they should flag diamond mods and then it's eventually post deletion in that scenario too.

Comment: @Lundin for context, that user [asked already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421017/over-motivated-moderation) on meta, but then deleted the question.

Comment: I'm feeling a little sorry for the OP here, without specifics I took a look at [one of his answers that I found was deleted for plagiarism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29794269/1663001) and it basically says "here's some code on a website that will help <code>". So in my mind it isn't plagiarism if you are crediting the original source. In fact, the link had expired which is exactly why we don't have link-only answers.

Comment: (not saying the notice above doesn't deserve a flag though, that's a different issue)

Comment: @Lino Well... without any concrete examples that's a pretty meaningless question and just comes across as a rant. Though I suppose the OP might have trouble finding their own posts if they were deleted.

Comment: @DavidG That's weird... how can it be plagiarism if the source was stated? It could be deleted as link-only/not adding anything of value to SO... but the mod left an explicit comment stating it was plagiarised. I suppose it might depend on what manner of copyright the original source was under. Though common sense might suggest that if someone doesn't want anyone to copy their copyright material, then don't go posting it on the f-ing Internet in the first place...

Comment: @Lundin Yup, exactly. The mod even went to the trouble of finding the (now defunct) page on the Wayback Machine to link to it, and that says the content is Creative Commons 2.5/

Comment: @DavidG  the content was deleted as it wasn't in quote blocks, and gave the impression the work was the OP's own work: [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29794269/1).

Comment: My rule of thumb is that we (the regular visitors) curate content, we do not moderate people.  So as soon as you find yourself in a position where you should be moderating a person... flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yep, that edit has all kinds of looking for a fight written all over it.

Flag it and **walk away**. At this point, it's best for diamond mods to get involved.

Comment: To add to this: rolling back or commenting publishes your user profile. If the user has enough rep (to e.g. downvote), they might go after your posts. I've had this happen several times. A mod-flag is the anonymous way out, preventing any possible fall-out from the OP's side.

Comment: @Adriaan Isn't that ("go after your posts") some kind of serial downvoting that is automatically handled?

Comment: @OcasoProtal Not if they are smart. Tricks are publicly known to somewhat circumvent the serial voting :)